# How to declare default-function for a class?

Tags: typescript, class, default, function-call-operator

The [Function Call Operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Function_call_operator) in C++ allows a class to act like it were a function. I have used it in a logging class where something like this:

```cpp
logger.setFileName("./debug.log");
logger.log("Log this message");
```

turns into this:

```cpp
logger.setFileName("./debug.log");
logger("Log this message");
```

And now I would like to use [Function Call Operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Function_call_operator) or something in that direction in type-script (to provide a default-function for my class), but how do we achieve such a declaration in type-script?

Should we rather make a feature request at [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would need to be a [JavaScript proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposals).

You can't make a JavaScript `class` that behaves like this, but you can make a regular function that acts like that, though it takes some gymnastics:

```
interface Logger {
  (message: string): void;
  setFileName(filename: string): void;
}

const logger = function (message: string) {

} as Logger;

logger.setFileName = function (filename: string) {

}

logger.setFileName("./debug.log");
logger("Log this message");
```

**Edit**: here's [an example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Logger%20%7B%0A%20%20(message%3A%20string)%3A%20void%3B%0A%20%20setFileName(filename%3A%20string)%3A%20void%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20createLogger%20%3D%20()%3A%20Logger%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20let%20_filename%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20const%20logger%20%3D%20function%20Logger(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(_filename%2C%20message)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%20as%20Logger%3B%0A%0A%20%20logger.setFileName%20%3D%20function%20setFileName(filename%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20_filename%20%3D%20filename%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20return%20logger%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20logger1%20%3D%20createLogger()%3B%0Aconst%20logger2%20%3D%20createLogger()%3B%0Alogger1.setFileName(%22.%2Fdebug1.log%22)%3B%0Alogger2.setFileName(%22.%2Fdebug2.log%22)%3B%0Alogger1(%22one%22)%3B%0Alogger2(%22two%22)%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Output%3A%0A%2F%2F%20.%2Fdebug1.log%20one%0A%2F%2F%20.%2Fdebug2.log%20two) that uses a `createLogger()` factory function to create multiple instances with state stored in function scope:

```
interface Logger {
  (message: string): void;
  setFileName(filename: string): void;
}

const createLogger = (): Logger => {
  let _filename: string;
  const logger = function (message: string) {
    console.log(_filename, message);
  } as Logger;

  logger.setFileName = function (filename: string) {
    _filename = filename;
  }

  return logger;
}

const logger1 = createLogger();
const logger2 = createLogger();
logger1.setFileName("./debug1.log");
logger2.setFileName("./debug2.log");
logger1("one");
logger2("two");

// Output:
// ./debug1.log one
// ./debug2.log two
```

Comment: Using this approach, how and where would we store the `filename` variable?

Comment: You could store in module scope or in function scope using an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE). Like I said... a bit of gymnastics to achieve it.

Comment: Is having multiple instances of `logger`, with separate `filename` property for each of them possible? (when yes, could you update your answer to demonstrate it)

Comment: It's certainly possible, but you'd have to use some non-`class` method of instantiation, like a `createLogger` factory function.